# Magento 1.9 store pickup google map marker not display

Tags: google-maps, magento

I have installed magestore store pickup module in magento 1.9 and configured it as mentioned in document. While accessing the our stores page https://www.batterymasteronline.com/storepickup/ and click on marker, the store info is not displaying, its showing following error in console.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'childElements' of undefined
at klass.beautyInfoWindow (storemanager.js:821)
at klass.openInfoWindow (storemanager.js:892)
at klass.clickMarkerCallBack (storemanager.js:793)
at _.Zf.<anonymous> (prototype.js:399)
at we.j (js?key=MY_API_KEY&sensor=false&libraries=places,geometry:211)
at Object._.O.trigger (jskey=MY_API_KEY&sensor=false&libraries=places,geometry:208)
at fU.<anonymous> (marker.js:31)
at we.j (js?key=MY_API_KEY&sensor=false&libraries=places,geometry:211)
at Object._.O.trigger (js?key=MY_API_KEY&sensor=false&libraries=places,geometry:208)
at Object.onClick (marker.js:24)
beautyInfoWindow @ storemanager.js:821
openInfoWindow @ storemanager.js:892
clickMarkerCallBack @ storemanager.js:793
(anonymous) @ prototype.js:399
we.j @ js?key=MY_API_KEY&sensor=false&libraries=places,geometry:211
_.O.trigger @ js?key=MY_API_KEY&sensor=false&libraries=places,geometry:208
(anonymous) @ marker.js:31
we.j @ js?key=MY_API_KEY&sensor=false&libraries=places,geometry:211_.O.trigger @ js?key=MY_API_KEY&sensor=false&libraries=places,geometry:208
onClick @ marker.js:24_.r.onClick @ common.js:145H._.Xo.Wa @ common.js:64
```

Comment: Are you still having this issue? Your info windows show up fine upon marker click from my side.

Comment: I fixed this issues, by some small change in lib

Comment: Glad to hear! :)